# Choose picture Intent causes nullpointer exception

Tags: android, image

```
 public void uploadpicture(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                    "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                 {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) 
                     {

                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    Toast.makeText(this,selectedImagePath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("selectedImagePath",selectedImagePath.trim());

                }

            }


        }
```

I got the this from Log-cat:

```
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.sec.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5147009501910019474 }} to activity {ncpl.talentapp/ncpl.talentapp.SignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2821)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2864)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1057)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 15:57:51.054: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 9):

From your log it looks like you are trying to pick an image from Picasa folder `dat=content://com.android.sec.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5147009501910019474`, and these must be handled differently, because data in `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` column will be null for them.
You can see how to handle picking images from Picasa correctly at this link:

http://dimitar.me/how-to-get-picasa-images-using-the-image-picker-on-android-devices-running-any-os-version/

Only you also need to handle URIs that start with "content://com.sec.android.gallery3d" (I see this on Samsung S3) so change

```
if (selectedImage.toString().startsWith("content://com.google.android.gallery3d"))
```

to

```
if (_selectedImage.toString().startsWith("content://com.google.android.gallery3d") 
    || selectedImage.toString().startsWith("content://com.sec.android.gallery3d"))
```

I'm not sure if there are any more special cases (probably yes).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem and tried implementing this based on the website user1682516 recommended. I was banging my head against the wall because my Picasa content URLs didn't quite match: mine looked like "com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider" and not "com.android.gallery3d.provider" but didn't seem to work whether I altered the URL or not.

Then I felt dumb when I eventually realized that the library I use to load remote images for ImageViews in my app, https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader, takes care of this for me. I can just call ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage() with the appropriate parameters and get a Bitmap in the callback. I don't need to worry about whether it is a local image, a remote Picasa image, or an ordinary remote image--that's taken care of for me. Wish I had figured that out hours ago!

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Samsung SM-A520F. Works if you want to pick only local images from your gallery:

```
fun uploadpicture(view: View?) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true) // Restrict choice
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Tested Code here

```
public class SelectPhotoActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE); 
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
           // here you can set the image
            }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: it works fine for some pictures in samsung ...Some pictures got null pointer exception

Comment: Length of those pictures may be large

Comment: "Use this whole other piece of code", while *arguably* helping with the immediate problem (and arguably not even doing that, since you can't just paste this code into the existing class), does nothing to help anyone know what's wrong with the original code.