# How to get picasa picture thumbnail

Tags: android, thumbnails, picasa

Getting an image from the Gallery with

```
Intent intentGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intentGallery, CHOOSE_PICTURE);
```

and

```
Uri targetUri = data.getData();
Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Data achieved from gallery: "+ targetUri);
```

results in content://com.android.sec.gallery3d.provider/picasa/ if the user selected a Picasa image.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491413/1862877) is not good for me, because i don't want to use internet.

So, there is a way to pick only the local picasa image thumbnail from gallery?