# Unable to get image from picker ACTION_GET_CONTENT for Picasa images on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

My [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aadhk.woinvoice) fails to load a bitmap for a small percentage of instances where users pick images.

My code to pick an image is like this:

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*");`

Then my code to open the bitmap is:

`InputStream input = activity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (input == null)
      throw new NullPointerException("Null returned from openInputStream for: " + uri);`

I then get exceptions like this:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Null returned from openInputStream
>   for:
>   content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/5884758542207200626
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Null returned from openInputStream
>   for:
>   content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/6064868645826106994

Comment: Do you hold `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions?

Comment: Yes, the app holds WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Are you asking for the `InputStream` right away (e.g., in `onActivityResult()`)? Or are you persisting the `Uri` somewhere (e.g., database) and trying to access it some time later?

Comment: I'm asking for the InputStream right away

Comment: I can't repro the problem, any images I pick using this open just fine.  Most of my users don't have issues.  But, some do.

Comment: Well, if all the URLs are `com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider`, that's Samsung's stuff (`com.sec`), and perhaps they have a bug. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735562/choose-picture-intent-causes-nullpointer-exception

Comment: Thanks, I am trying out using universal-image-loader to solve the issue!  Any ideas how to test/repro this? Does Samsung have images with that stuff installed for the simulator?

Comment: I am not aware that Samsung distributes their firmware in emulator form. They have a remote device lab IIRC, but it may not have any images to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I used this library to load images, it looks like it handles the com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider case and many more:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader