# How can I get a Picasa image folder on my Marshmallow device?

Tags: android, picasa

My application allows users to select an image to upload. When users select an image from a picasa album my data intent comes back with `dat=content://com.sec.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/...`.

Apparently when selecting an image from a picasa folder, I must handle getting the image differently as noted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12491413/1438339).

But before I implement a fix, I want to be able to reproduce the crash so I can verify my fix actually works. **So how can I get a Picasa folder on my new (marshmallow) Android test device since Picasa has been killed by Google?**

Comment: you can create folder using file explorer android device monitor. (the little android icon beside device manager and SDK manager)

Answer (score 0):

The most guaranteed way of getting a file send inside an intent, is to open a stream to it and copy it over to a private folder on your app.

This way works for local file, `content` uri, picasa, all of it.

Something like that:

```
private File getSharedFile() {
    Uri uri = intent.getExtras().getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    // or using the new compat lib
    Uri uri = ShareCompat.IntentReader(this).getStream();

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;

    try {
       File f = ... define here a temp file // maybe getCacheDir();
       is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
       os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));

       int read;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

       while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
          os.write(bytes, 0, read);
       }
       return f;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           ... handle exceptions, buffer underflow, NPE, etc
       } finally {
          try { is.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* u never know */ }
          try {
            os.flush();
            os.close();
          } catch (Exception e) { /* seriously can happen */ }
       }
      return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and I'd like to test this out, but only after I can reproduce the crash by selecting an image from a Picasa folder. Do you know answer to my original question?

Comment: `com.sec.android` is from old samsung devices. I guess u need a Galaxy S3 to reproduce it. I really understand your concern, but the app I work on have average 700K monthly active users from all over the world and one of the core features is receive receive intent images. Believe me, this code I passed to you will work.

Comment: PS.: the code above is an I/O operation that will often be a network I/O operation. You absolutely can not do it on the UI thread.